# How can I tell from the logs that a request to my Tomcat server used HTTP or HTTPS?

Tags: apache, tomcat, https

I'm changed my iPhone app from using HTTP to using HTTPS and it just worked.

I doubt that it is actually working though. How can I check, from  my Tomcat server log files (or similar), that the request actually used HTTPS?

Comment: Remove the plaintext connector from server.xml. If the client app still works, it must be using whatever connector is left.

Comment: I can't. My Android app still uses the HTTP connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log the return value of `request.isSecure()` from a Servlet or JSP and see.

BUT: be aware that Tomcat, if not configured properly, won't KNOW if it's serving securely or not.  This is the case whether your SSL cert terminates at your load balancer (or web server sitting in front of Tomcat), or if Tomcat is handling SSL traffic directly.  Your  (in server.xml) for HTTPS requests must have the `secure="true"` attribute; the default is "false".  If `secure` is set to false (or not set), then Tomcat may be successfully handling SSL connections, but when you call `isSecure()` from within a Servlet (or JSP), it'll return false.

I don't know if the `secure` attribute affects how Tomcat logs traffic or not, but it may.

Comment: +1 for the actual answer, but the rest of this is incorrect. If SSL is terminated at an Apache HTTPD in front of Tomcat, request.isSecure() will return true when appropriate. Apache send a the appropriate headers to make it so.

Comment: Thanks @EJP.  I've dealt with Tomcat configs where I couldn't rely on request.isSecure(), although in those cases it wasn't Apache but a load balancer in front of Tomcat.  That was an older version of Tomcat (not v7); sounds like perhaps this has been fixed in v7; I hope so!  Causes all sorts of problems, including not being able to do a 302 redirect to a fully qualified https URL.  Ouch.